# Need to add auto increment column in a table using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have to create a table using hive.  But I want to create that table with auto increment column.

i have googled but not able to find the exact answer. 
If Anybody knows the syntax for it . Please share it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a UDF (user defined function) for it. I have successfully used the UDF in this link 
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/udf/UDFRowSequence.java

Further you can learn the use of UDF in hive by [this very helpful tutorial](http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/08/10/guide-to-writing-hive-udfs.html).

Comment: If the instance of the UDF is garbadged and a new one instanciated, will the count restart to 0?

Comment: This works when we select row_sequence, How about adding it as a column in new table or existing table.

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO TEST_INC SELECT
reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID"), test1, test2, test3 from TEST;
```

for example.

Answer (score 1):

You got to write a UDF for this purpose. Take a look at the following Jira discussion

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1304.

Download the following [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12447780/HIVE-1304.3.patch) file and try it

This can be applied only for small input. Since the UDF `row_sequence()` is used in the reducer and the reducer count should be kept 1 inorder to keep the autoincrement field distinct