# Adding Auto Increment Column in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, user-defined-functions, udf

While the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082763/need-to-add-auto-increment-column-in-a-table-using-hive) instructs to use UDF, It still does not add as a new column in existing table or even new table. It works only for SELECT statement. 
Any workaround for this?

Mods: I was not certain this could be answered in the linked question above, so creating new one. Please move if you feel this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment has many complications in hive, if you want a unique value you can try hash(column1,column2) function where column1 is a unique value and column2 is timestamp.